# determinat of complex entries of $1\times 1$, $2\times 2$ is it still like real?

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis

Trying to get my basics right. Cannot recall dealing with determinants of complex numbers. Is the determinant still the same for complex numbers than in real numbers ? Interested in $1\times 1$, $2\times 2$ to keep it simple.

For $1\times 1$,  $$ det(Z_{1x1})=x_{11}+iy_{11}.$$
Recall from what I have read from complex analysis $$|Z|=|x+iy|=\sqrt{x^2+y^2} $$
but that is not the determinant!?
Also determinant of a $2\times 2$ $$\begin{vmatrix} 
               z_{11} & z_{12} 
             \\ z_{21} & z_{22 }\end{vmatrix} 
=z_{11}z_{22}-z_{12}z_{21}$$

Also, is there some critical property that does not hold that is important where it does not  for real entries?

Comment: What is the determinant of *a complex number*.  Do you mean to ask for the determinant *of a matrix with complex entries*?

Comment: @JMoravitz yes that is what i mean. Interested matrix with complex

Comment: In that case, the determinant is defined exactly the same way.  Keep in mind that properties involving linear dependence/independence of vectors will now take values from $\Bbb C$ instead of $\Bbb R$ as your scalar field.  As for why the determinant is not the same as the modulus, why would it be?  The determinant is not even a norm, it is an invariant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The determinant is defined the same way no matter what your entries are, essentially as long as it makes sense to multiply and add them. It still holds that the matrix is invertible iff its determinant is invertible.